# Animations pause for a slight moment when reaching end frame

Tags: animation

I recently copied over some Blender files from my old computer to my new one.

I noticed the the animations are freezing on the last frame for just a moment. This is making my animation loops not seamless and choppy at the end of the animation. I pulled up the same file on my old computer and it was fine but for some reason it doesn't work on my laptop.

Comment: My animation is currently set up that way and is on my old computer as well. Since posting the question I have found that this is a bug that some people have experienced. Thank you for your suggestion if you have any more please send them.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the length of the sequence by 1 frame (so rather than, say, starting on from 1 and ending on frame 300, end on frame 299).